# Possibility to trigger Azure Logic App on a CRON expression

Tags: cron, azure-logic-apps

I currently have an Azure Function which runs on a schedule dictated by a CRON expression in the function itself.

For business reasons I now want to have this Function run on an HTTP trigger, sent by a Logic App.

The problem is that I can't see how to schedule the Logic App using a CRON expression. The Logic App's `Recurrence` mechanism permits me to specify a period based on one denomination of time, *i.e.* every *x* hours, minutes, *etc*.

[image]

Is it possible to specify, for example, the schedule described by this CRON expression:

> 0 30 0-5,13-23 * * 0-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, we can't set `cron` expression in `azure logic app`, you can set your `Recurrence` in this way, please set your `Frequency` to `week`:

[image]

I found that someone has put forward this suggestion in the feedback, you can vote for him, the development team will pay attention：

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/19597768-timer-trigger-cron-scheduling